# How to get the value of the parent element from the current element in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

How to get parent node value using XSLT and XPath, for below xml response : `<cartridge name="Standard Grid Wall" type="StandardGridWall">` , I want to get value of type . Please help

Comment: <cartridge name="Standard Grid Wall" type="StandardGridWall">

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Do not post your code in comments, use `\`\`` (backticks) or indent to get a colorized codeblock. Always show what you have tried and where you are, see [mcve].

Comment: Your code snippet does not have a parent node. What is your context, what is the XSLT you have tried, show a snippet input and output and how you want it to change.

Comment: Btw, the short answer to _"how to get parent node value"_ is `<xsl:value-of select="parent::node()" />`. So I would assume you mean something else entirely, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

*Apparently, my comment helped, so here it is, posting it as answer:*

How to get the value of the parent node? Use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="parent::node()" />
```